# Input must have 4 axes, corresponding to (num, channels, height, width)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, caffe, nvidia-digits

Not sure if this is an issue or not - but I have been searching for days and cannot seem to figure it out!

Any image I try to classify individually using digits seems to run okay. However, when using the "classify many images" button, the network crashes because of the aforementioned title/bug/I don't even know what the hell it is.

I'm entirely new to caffe and DIGITS, and as I said I've spent days googling this problem - and cant seem to figure it out. What is the 5th dimension on the image, and if I do actually have 5D images, how do I convert them to 4D?

Comment: your question is not clear. can you describe (code and/or DIGITS screen shots) what exactly are you doing that causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug - Posted on git and they flagged it officially and patched - to anyone else experiencing this problem, update your DIGITS files